# Python: How to quit a recursive function when an error arises interrupting the program

Tags: python, function, recursion, exception

Say I have a recursive function like

```
def func(n, lis):
    if n == 1:
        return lis
    else:
        lis = func(n-1, lis[:-1])
        print(n,lis)
        lis.append(n)
        if len(lis) < 5:
            return lis
        else:
            return 'Error'
```

and if I run

```
print (func(6, [6,5,4,3,2,1]))
```

I get

```
2 [6]
3 [6, 2]
4 [6, 2, 3]
5 [6, 2, 3, 4]
6 Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Python/test.py", line 324, in <module>
    print (func(6, [6,5,4,3,2,1]))
  File "d:/Python/test.py", line 314, in func
    lis.append(n)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The function reads the return of `func(5, [6,2,3,4,5])`, which is `'Error'`, and puts it into `func`, arising an `AttributeError`. This is not what I want since it stops the program. I tried

```
class AtLeastFive(Exception):
    pass

def func(n, lis):
    if n == 1:
        return lis
    else:
        lis = func(n-1, lis[:-1])
        print(n,lis)
        lis.append(n)
        if len(lis) < 5:
            return lis
        else:
            raise AtLeastFive
```

But this still interrupts the program. I need to run the function for a series of lists, so I don't want `Exception`. What I want is something like

```
for lis in lists:
    func(n, lis)
```

but it stops when there is an exception. Is it possible to quit the function when bad things happen without interupting the loop?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, your function `func` should ultimately return `Error` for the arguments that you are passing to it. If that is the case, then the following code should work:

```py
def func(n, lis):
    if n == 1:
        return lis
    else:
        lis = func(n-1, lis[:-1])
        print(n,lis)
        # test to see if return value is `Error` and if so, return it:
        if lis == 'Error':
            return lis
        lis.append(n)
        if len(lis) < 5:
            return lis
        else:
            return 'Error'

print (func(6, [6,5,4,3,2,1]))
```

Prints:

```
2 [6]
3 [6, 2]
4 [6, 2, 3]
5 [6, 2, 3, 4]
6 Error
Error
```